# Tips para evaluar los controles de los mapas de riesgos de los procesos del SIGC en la Gobernación

Tags: controller

Tips para evaluar los controles de los mapas de riesgos de los procesos del SIGC en la Gobernación.

En el desarrollo de la actividad de Evaluación de Controles se han vivido experiencias que pueden ser útiles para realización de las próximas evaluaciones

Answer (score 1):

Las bases están en los roles de la oficina de control interno. Función Pública tiene esta guía https://www.funcionpublica.gov.co/web/eva/biblioteca-virtual/-/document_library/bGsp2IjUBdeu/view_file/35026379

También está la guía de riesgos
https://www.funcionpublica.gov.co/web/eva/biblioteca-virtual/-/document_library/bGsp2IjUBdeu/view_file/34316499